# How do you use a webfont npm package like @mdi/light-font in React Native (iOS/Android) with @oblador/react-native-vector-icons?

Tags: react-native, webfonts, react-native-vector-icons, material-design-icons

I would like to use the following icon webfont in React Native: [@mdi/light-font](https://github.com/Templarian/MaterialDesignLight)

I'm using [@oblador/react-native-vector-icons](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons) to manage my web fonts. I don't use Expo.

Currently I have used the .svg exports of @mdi/light-font and repackaged it as a custom font with Fontello. Then I used react-native-vector-icons helper function to import Fontello.

And suddenly I have the feeling that I'm making my life much more difficult with no reasons.

I've seen that there is a ttf file I could push to android. However I don't find how to import a glyphMap.

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not really sure how React Native works as I've never used it but couldn't you just use @mdi/react with @mdi/light-js? We really advise against using webfonts for icons where possible, though if you're making your own subset it shouldn't be as bad for users as importing the full font file.

Comment: Hi @JamesCoyle, thanks for your feedback. It is interesting. What would you use rather than a font? .svg files?

Comment: We offer @mdi/js and @mdi/light-js which give you the SVG paths for all icons as javascript strings. You can then use those paths directly in code. For react native I think you can use something like the [react-native-svg-icon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-svg-icon) package to render these paths. Our paths are all designed for a 24x24 viewbox.

Comment: Thanks, I get it. Yes, it is more straightforward.